# SQL Server Insert Without INTO

Tags: sql, sql-server, insert

This may be a really basic SQL question, but I have seen a SQL **INSERT** statement without the clause **INTO** and I was wondering if that is some special case in SQL Server 2000 or 2008.

The INSERT statement look something like

```
INSERT <table_name>
(
  column names
)
select *
from <another table>
where <condition>
```

Sorry, if this is super basic, but I just wanted to make sure.
Thanks!

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The INTO is [optional](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa933206%28v=sql.80%29.aspx). It is required in [ANSI](http://www.w3schools.com/SQL/sql_insert.asp) sql but the MS/Sybase developers decided to make it optional.

Comment: Thanks. I just ran an insert statement with and without the INTO clause and the results are the same.

Answer (score 6):

Check the BNF grammar http://savage.net.au/SQL/

92, 99, SQL:2003

```
<insert statement> ::= INSERT INTO <insertion target> <insert columns and source>
```

According to the ANSI spec, INTO should only be optional in a `MERGE` clause.

For [SQL Server](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa933206%28v=sql.80%29.aspx) (this link from 2000 to show how old it is - it exists from the first version of SQL Server), it is **optional**.  It is also optional for MySQL.

```
INSERT [ INTO]
    { table_name WITH ( < table_hint_limited > [ ...n ] )
        | view_name
        | rowset_function_limited
    }

    {    [ ( column_list ) ]
        { VALUES
            ( { DEFAULT | NULL | expression } [ ,...n] )
            | derived_table
            | execute_statement
        }
    }
    | DEFAULT VALUES
```

Answer (score 4):

From MSDN:

> INTO is an optional keyword that can
>   be used between INSERT and the target
>   table.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa933206%28v=sql.80%29.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You mention that this comes from an early version of SQL. If you have 2005 onwards running now you can drop the INTO.